# Modificar el DOM en React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

¿Se pueden utilizar, los métodos de javascript para acceder o modificar el DOM como `.document.getElementById, .getAttribute, .setAttribute etc...` en React?

He visto que se pueden utilizar los `refs` para seleccionar un nodo pero en mi caso necesito acceder a los hijos o cambiar alguno de sus atributos y no se si es correcto hacerlo, o debería cambiarlo. Dejo un ejemplo donde he utilizado javascript para hacer un svg.

```js
import React from "react";
import {v4} from 'uuid';

export default class PieChart extends React.Component {
    render() {
        let viewBox = ` -${this.props.width * 2} -${this.props.width * 1.2} ${this.props.width * 4.5} ${this.props.width * 2.3}`
        let transform = "rotate(0 0 0)"; //if you want it rotated a certain angle change the first number in the this transform object
        return (
            <div className="borde itemX1" >
                <h4 className="fullWidth">Detalle de Etapa</h4>
                <div className="centerPie">
                    <svg id="svg" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox={viewBox} transform={transform}>
                        {getPaths(this.props.slices, this.props.width)}
                    </svg>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

function getCoordinatesForPercent(percent) {

    const x = Math.cos(2 * Math.PI * percent);
    const y = Math.sin(2 * Math.PI * percent);
    return [x, y];
}


let cumulativePercent = 0;

const getPaths = (slices, size) => {
    let paths = [];
    slices.forEach((slice, index) => {

        let [startX, startY] = getCoordinatesForPercent(cumulativePercent);

        cumulativePercent += slice.percent;

        const [endX, endY] = getCoordinatesForPercent(cumulativePercent);

        const largeArcFlag = slice.percent > .5 ? 1 : 0;

        const pathData = [
            `M ${startX * size} ${startY * size}`, // Move
            `A ${size} ${size} 0 ${largeArcFlag} 1 ${endX * size} ${endY * size}`, // Arc (size is same as radius)
            `L 0 0 Z`, // Line
        ].join(' ');

        let medioX = ((startX * size) + (endX * size)) / 2;
        let medioY = ((startY * size) + (endY * size)) / 2;

        let translateX;
        let translateY;

        function enter(e) {
            translateX = -medioX / 10;
            translateY = -medioY / 10;
            if (slice.percent < 0.5) {
                translateX = -translateX;
                translateY = -translateY;
            }
            if (!e.target.getAttribute('transform')) {
                let x = e.target.parentElement.children;
                [...x].filter(p => p.tagName !== "g").map(p => {
                    p.setAttribute('transform', '');
                    p.setAttribute('class', '');
                    return null;
                })
                e.target.setAttribute('transform', 'translate(' + translateX + ',' + translateY + ')');
                e.target.setAttribute('class', 'sliceSeleccionado')
            }
            else {
                e.target.setAttribute('transform', '');
                e.target.setAttribute('class', '');
            }
        }

        const style = {
            'fill': slice.color,
            'strokeWidth': 3,
            'stroke': 'rgb(0, 0, 0)'
        }
        paths.push(<path className="" onClick={enter} d={pathData} fill={slice.color} key={v4()} />)
        paths.push(
            <g transform="translate(400 -300)" key={v4()}>
                <rect width="20" height="20" style={style} transform={"translate(" + (10) + " " + (-10 + index * 50) + ")"} />
                <text x="40" fill={slice.color} fontSize="2em" transform={"translate(" + (10) + " " + (10 + index * 50) + ")"}>Lorem Ipsum</text>
            </g>
        )
    });
    return paths;
}
```

Se podrían utilizar `.target, .parentElement, .children, setAttribute` o hay alguna otra manera de hacerlo

Comment: De poder hacerlo, puedes hacerlo, siempre que estés obteniendo el objeto en el DOM, con las referencias desde luego puedes hacerlo. Pero piensa que todos los atributos y cosas que puedes hacer con javascript nativo, es algo que puedes hacer con react y de una forma más fácil (en mi opinión), lo cierto es que al final es un código más legible

Comment: Además, cualquier cambio que hagas fuera del ciclo de vida de los componentes de React se puede perder en el siguiente *repintado* de los mismos

Comment: @GermanAlzate De que forma lo haría con React, no he encontrado nada para los atributos.

Comment: @PabloLozano Lo de los atributos se lo he asociado al ´onClick´ del path asi que no debería afectar a la hora de renderizarlo no?

Comment: La verdad es que @PabloLozano tiene la razón, en cada render puedes perder algunas configuraciones, más si no están en el state, además que el procesado puede ser hasta mayor. En el momento no puedo responderte todo y cambiar todo tu código, pero piensa que tu puedes hacer algo así `<path className={condicion ? 'active': 'inactive'} />` y sería equivalente a en tu onClick hacer esto `e.target.setAttribute('class', condition ? 'active' : 'inactive')`. Parte de ahí, investiga bastante, lee bastante, documentate

Comment: Eso es lo que tenía pensado hacer, soy bastante nuevo con React y no me queda muy claro donde utilizar un state o no. Pero creo que voy a poner un Boolean en el state para saber si le ha dado click o no y alguna otra cosa para saber si hay algún otro que este clickeado.

Comment: No lo he dicho pero se trata de un gráfico circular y lo de los atributos es para que le ponga un borde al hacerle click a cada porción.

Comment: No hay problema en hacerlo usando `refs`. Crea un `ref` para el componente o componentes que quieres manejar y luego, por medio de `current`, tienes el nodo sobre el cual puedes ejecutar los métodos y propiedades comunes.

Answer (score 0):

Si necesitas acceder a elementos dentro de un componente tuyo, lo recomendado es hacerlo mediante [refs](https://es.reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) de react. Mediante una ref vas a poder acceder a cualquier elemento de tu component y vas a poder modificarlo.

De esta manera vas a acceder más directamente a un elemento y de una forma más controlada, además los ref te facilita las cosas a la hora de hacer los test de tus componentes.

Te recomiendo leer la documentación de react para esto :).
Espero te sea útil la respuesta.
Saludos!!

Comment: en tu respuesta debería venir también la forma de resolverlo con el código, posterior dejas un enlace a dicho recurso solo como referencia